# creating an interface and implement it in another package

Tags: java, oop, interface

> Create an interface containing three methods, in its own package.
>   Implement the interface in a different package. Prove that all the
>   methods in an interface are automatically public.

This is the question above which I have got as an assignment, and I am allowed to get help from anywhere.
What I have tried is:

**file 01: Student.java**

```
package student;
public interface Students
{
    void RollNo();
    void course();
    void marks();
}
```

**file 02: MyMain.java**

```
import student.*;
class Test1 implements Students
{
    void RollNo()
    {
        System.out.println("18CS35");
    }
    void course()
    {
        System.out.println("OOP");
    }
    void marks()
    {
        System.out.println("85");
    }
}
class MyMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test1 t = new Test1();
        t.RollNo();
        t.course();
        t.marks();
    }
}
```

What I did is, compiled File 01 and created a package (folder in same direcotry)
When I compile file 02, I get this error.

> `MyMain`.java:2: error: cannot access `Students class Test1 implements Students`
>                          ^   bad class file: .\Students.class
>       class file contains wrong class: student.`Students`
>       Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Commands I am using to compile:

```
javac –d . Student.java
javac Student.java      
javac MyMain.java
```

Comment: Could be a screwed up classpath.  Please [edit] your question to include the *exact* commands you are using to compile.

Comment: The methods cannot be more restrictive in the child class

Comment: What IDE are you using? I'd suggest picking a smart Java IDE and you won't have troubles with this assignment :)

Comment: if you add your package at file 01, do so in in file 02, too please.

Comment: Maybe you need create a folder called student, for your package, and put Student.java/Student.class inside that student folder. This may apply for your MyMain.java/class also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the interface in the student package:

```
package student;

public interface Student {
    void rollNo();

    void course();

    void marks();
}
```

then in another package, declare your MyMain class

```
package anotherpackage;

import student.Student;

public class MyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 t = new Test1();
        t.rollNo();
        t.course();
        t.marks();
    }
}

class Test1 implements Student {
    @Override
    public void rollNo() {
        System.out.println("18CS35");
    }

    @Override
    public void course() {
        System.out.println("OOP");
    }

    @Override
    public void marks() {
        System.out.println("85");
    }
}
```

- The file is called `MyMain.java` and the `MyMain` class must be declared `public` inside it. **This is important**. You must have one and only one public class in the file with the same name as the file.
- `Test1` on the other hand is not declared public.
- You don't have to add the `@Override` annotations, but it is good practice to always add them when you implement or override a method;

**To get it to work:**

- stick `Student.java` in a directory called `student`
- stick `MyMain.java` in a directory called `anotherpackage`

then compile

```
javac student/Student.java
javac anotherpackage/MyMain.java
```

and run:

```
java anotherpackage/MyMain
```

outputs:

```
18CS35
OOP
85
```

**The proof:**

Note that when you implement your methods, you need to declare them public, otherwise the compiler will complain that you reduce their visibility. That proves that they are considered public in the interface.

Comment: Thanks, but I have still a problem with the file directories, can you help me by remote using my pc?
PS: I am a beginner in java

Comment: @VishwasLuhana the directories have the same name as the packages, make sure you did not make a typo in the directories or package names.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface's methods are public by default (interface methods are always publich). Your implementation's methods have default visibility. An implementation can't have a lower visibility than the interface or abstract method it's implementing.

Just declare your methods in the Student-class public.

Comment: Thanks, after doing public program compiled successfully but now this is the error
Error: Could not find or load main class MyMain
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: student/MyMain (wrong name: MyMain)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the commands you're using to compile the code, it looks like you've put both `Students.java` and `MyMain.java` in the same directory. Since `Students` is supposed to be in a package named `student`, your directory structure should be like below, because Java looks for the `.class` files in directories according to the package names.

```
student/
    Students.java
    Students.class
MyMain.java
MyMain.class
```

Or if you have separate source and build directories:

```
src/
    student/
        Students.java
    MyMain.java
build/
    student/
        Students.class
    MyMain.class
```

All of this should be handled automatically if you use an IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ IDEA.